# filebeats multiline javastack

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, filebeat

So i have tried a number of ways to carve this up and get file beats to process multiple lines but i feel as though i am missing something.

Example of the logfile when a stack hits.:

```
2022-05-10_12:01:40.21362 '[2022-05-10 12:01:40,213] [appJobLow-4] ERROR c.m.c.example - listIpPools: com.example.vim25.NoPermission: Permission to perform this operation was denied.
2022-05-10_12:01:40.21367 'com.example.vim25.NoPermission: Permission to perform this operation was denied.
2022-05-10_12:01:40.21367   at jdk.internal.reflect.asdf.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2022-05-10_12:01:40.21368   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.asdf.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

My multiple attempts

```
  multiline.type: pattern
  #multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d*\s.[a-zA-z][a-zA-z]|^Caused by:'
  #multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d*\s...\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d*.\s.[a-zA-Z]+-\d{2}..|ERROR'
  #multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d*\s\s[a][t]'
  #multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d*[[:space:]]\t[a][t]'
  #multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d*[[:space:]]\'\'\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[[:space:]]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\][[:space:]]\[\w+-\d*\][[:space:]]ERROR'
  multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d*[[:space:]].+.+\[\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[[:space:]]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\][[:space:]]\[\w+-\d*\][[:space:]]ERROR'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
```

I am working with the latest release as well of file beats and elk.

The pattern is whats kicking my butt.  The first multiline.pattern was my original that worked well.  Since we updated the product it has eliminated the Caused by:

Any suggestions on the pattern?

Comment: I would be even ok with the second, third and beyond to match and make one message.  So anything with 'at' adds to the previous line.

Comment: i have also tried to change the negate and match a bit to see if i would have any success but no dice.